Field Types when creating kendra data source with boto3
I create my data source this way :
template = {
"connectionConfiguration":  {
    "repositoryEndpointMetadata":{
        "BucketName":"BUCKET"
    }
},
"repositoryConfigurations": {
    "document":{
        "fieldMappings":[
            {
                "indexFieldName":"MyField",
                "indexFieldType":"STRING", # only "STRING" is accepted ?
                "dataSourceFieldName":"MyField",
            }
        ]
    }
},
"syncMode": "FULL_CRAWL",
"type": "S3"
}

response = client.create_data_source(
    Name='data-source-test-api',
    IndexId=index_id,
    Type="TEMPLATE",
    Configuration={
        'TemplateConfiguration': {
            'Template': template
        }
    },
    RoleArn='ROLE',
    Tags=TAGS,
)
data_source_id = response['Id']

But I need to set indexFieldType to a string list.
I don't see how
I already tried : STRING_LIST, STRINGS, STRINGLIST, STRING LIST and [STRING]
how to make the indexFieldType a string list (like in the web UI) ?
